# How to Starting specific RC from selenium grid which is running through Hudson plugin?

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

My environment:

- Hudson -> with selenium grid plugin - Installed on linux machine
- Hudson -> Having 4 machines ( 1 linux , 3 Windows ) as node
- TestCases -> MyTestCases are in TestNG

In Hudson server I checked the selenium console `http://localhost:4444/console`.  It shows the node machines registered as RC with random port numbers.  I run the test (test is configured as another job) . Test is running on any one of the machine / RC.

But I want to execute tests on specific environment Machine 1 / Machine 3 . How can I achieve this?  What and how do I have to change the configuration files on selenium-grid on server to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to do this in Selenium 1.0. Hub can pass the command to any of the registered RCs. There are workarounds

- Easy way - Register RC ONLY from the machine you want to use for execution.
- A little harder way - In the RC machine that you are trying to execute the script, start the browser with a different name. If you are using *firefox now, change it to FirefoxForWindows or something similar. List of browsers will be there in grid console. Internally both will start tests on firefox browser only. Now you will have 3 RCs supporting *firefox browser and one supporting FirefoxOnWindows browser. Now change the browsername you pass to the test from *firefox to FirefoxOnWindows. Hub will see that only one machine has that configuration and it will pass the commands to that RC alone.

Answer (score 2):

If your machines are providing different environments, simply declare different environments in your grid_configuration.yml file and then have your client request those environments.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted, but for the record, I'm the guy that writes the RC support of Selenium Grid and maintained the Selenium Grid 1 project.  What is being asked for is only possible by declaring new environments and registering the appropriate machine with that environment.  There is simply no other way if you want to use Grid 1.  If you want to point a particular RC, you're free too, but you're not using Grid any longer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I too surprised for down voted for this Question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Selenium-1.0 for your test.The following link will help.
http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/run_the_demo.html

In the link it is mentioned how to give particular name to the RC while registering them to hub.

And using code how to connect to a particular env. in hub

Comment: Hi varun,
  In this example is about to start by manually right? how to do in selenium - grid by hudson.?

Comment: I havent used Selenium hudson integration. But I went through the details given on the hudson page. As much I can see you can use the slave label name along with the browser for execution of your test on a particular system. Following is the link I went through: [link]https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

Comment: If the above doesnt work then the other solution I can think of is, creating a job for grid with the grid jar. And independent RC jobs with RC jar and configure them accordingly.